# Restoring pg_dump file containing "COPY" via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I am currently trying to speed up the restoring of a database dump that is used  for testing on a Jenkins.

**Current situation:** The current dump (~15 MB) uses a huge amount of "INSERT"s to restore all the data in the DB. A many years old tool with JDBC is used to restore the dump and all newer update scripts (resulting from patches etc).

**Problem:** Newer dumps use "COPY" by default, but the tool seems to have problems with that. A simple statement.execute(sqlstring) seems to fail due to the stdin part. A copyManager.copyIn(sqlstring) fails with *ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"* (a \. follows after every copy command)
Example for a command:

```
COPY foo_data (id, cusid, tnmnid, usrid, some_text, more_text, archiv) FROM stdin;
\.
```

The source for using CopyManager:

```
CopyManager cpManager = ((BaseConnection) connection).getCopyAPI();

String sqlContent;
sqlContent = FileUtils.readFileToString(sqlFile, "UTF-8");
// The dump contains a user variable that needs to be replaced
sqlContent = StringUtils.replace(sqlContent, DB_USER, dbName);

cpManager.copyIn(sqlContent);
```

Am I maybe missing something?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It should make you suspicious that the `copyIn` method does not take a table name as argument…

The first argument to this function has to be a string with a [`COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) SQL statement.

The single parameter form of the function is only valid if the `COPY` statement names the file (on the database server!) from which data should be read, like

```
COPY tablename FROM '/path/to/datafile'
```

The forms with a second (and possibly third) parameter are for

```
COPY tablename FROM STDIN
```

Here the data are read from the database client, and you will have to supply them in the shape of a `java.io.Reader` or a `java.io.InputStream`.

Your code could look like this:

```java
try {
    org.postgresql.copy.CopyManager copy = ((org.postgresql.PGConnection)conn).getCopyAPI();
    java.io.FileReader infile = new java.io.FileReader("/home/laurenz/copydata");
    copy.copyIn("COPY copydest FROM STDIN (FORMAT 'csv')", infile);
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Could not read file with COPY data.");
}
```

Comment: `copyIn(someSqlString)` is a valid signature. The point is, that I don't want to restore only one table (that wouldn't be a problem I think) but a whole database including schemas, tables, functions etc.
Maybe I was mislead and this isn't even possible with `copyIn()`?

Comment: Right. `copyIn` is to copy table into (or out from) a single PostgreSQL table. You'd have to split up the dump file and extract the copy data into individual files, then you can load those. It is probably easier to fork a `psql` process...